# After gem update: test fail with "Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Since I updated several gems all tests fail with the error:

> ActionView::Template::Error: Asset was not declared to be precompiled
> in production.
>
> Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( favicons/manifest.json.erb )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
>
> app/views/layouts/_faviconsheader.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts__faviconsheader_html_erb__1320`
>
> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4340`

The error seems to refer to the partial `_faviconsheader.html.erb` that includes the line:

```
<%= content_tag :link, nil, rel: :manifest, href: image_path("favicons/manifest.json.erb") %>
```

This partial is loaded in `application.html.erb`: `<%= render partial: 'layouts/faviconsheader' %>`.

Any idea what is causing this error and what to do? **Before the gem update all tests passed.**

I use Rails 4.2.5. One of the gems updated was `sprockets` (updated sprockets to version 3.5.2). I read something on [github](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/266) about sprockets 4 having a problem, but I'm not using version 4.

---

P.S. Even if I add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( favicons/manifest.json.erb )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` the error persists. But even if that would have worked I would have wanted to understand why this problem has come about, without any changes except updating some gems.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Long Answer + Explanation**

I think the correct fix is to add the file to the precompiled assets, as recommended by the error message. Maybe that isn't fixing the issue for you because you've got an erb file that needs to be rendered at run time. I imagine if the file was a static json file then you would not still experience the issue after adding it to the precompiled assets.

When you use the `image_path` helper, Sprockets is assuming that you've got a static asset. The fact that your app didn't raise errors before `sprockets-rails` 3.0 is somewhat surprising. This new version is doing a better job, apparently, at enforcing the standards. (it also looks like there are other problems with 3.0 that might be updated shortly)

If you need to have erb inside the manifest, then it would be best practice to use a route path helper rather than `image_path` or `asset_path` to get the url. This would require you to add a manifest route to your `config/routes.rb` file and render the json file through a controller action. The view file would be your `.erb` manifest.

---

**Short Answer**

This started happening to me after doing a `bundler update` that changed my `sprockets-rails` version from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0. A simple fix is to revert `sprockets-rails` back to version 2.3.3 in your Gemfile and running `bundle install` again:

`gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.3.3'`

As an aside: I was experiencing this issue in development environment and was able to fix it there by running `rake assets:precompile`. Unfortunately, it didn't get my tests passing.

Comment: Yes, this also for me caused it / solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Sprockets 3.0 did it for me too

Comment: in my case, modify Gemfile to `gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.3.3'` and run `bundle update sprockets-rails `, then fixed.

Comment: This comment saved my rear end in August 2016, upgrading to Rails 5 on an older application and the sprockets upgrade broke all the things. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Though people have given long answers I suggest very simple and concise answer
Just go to

> **config/initializers/assets.rb**
>   and

Add the following line

> **Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *style.css* )**

where style.css can be replaced by your any file name for css

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar error.
I did not modify assets.rb or anything, just restart my server and no error anymore.

---

*ActionView::Template::Error (Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( rails.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server):
    10:   <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    11: 
    12: 
    13: <%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
    14:             'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
  app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___1806898863626708249_70312070486240'*

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and had to edit my manifest.js file in order to get it to work.

Edit `/assets/config.manifest.js` and then

```
// manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../stylesheets .css
```

Then do a `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: This worked for me! For some reason, despite my file having the extension `.scss`, I still had to use this in manifest.js: `//= link_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets .css` (note the css extension). I don't know why, but it wouldn't work without that